Swiper autoplay does not run on some browsers (for example, Samsung Internet mobile)
I'm using vue 2 + Nuxt 2.
<template>
  <section>
    <swiper-container
      ref="swiper"
      v-show="!bannersLoading && list.length > 0"
      class="main-page__main-slider cursor-pointer"
      data-slider-name="main-slider"
      init="false"
    >
      <swiper-slide
        v-for="({ id, photo, link, title }, index) in computedList"
        :key="id + 'slide-active-index-' + index"
        :data-color="title"
        class="categories__slider_item pa-0 ma-0 cursor-pointer main-slider__item"
        @click="$router.push(slideLink(link))"
      >
        <img :src="photo.filePath" alt="main-slider" class="h-100 w-100" />
      </swiper-slide>
    </swiper-container>
    <main-slider-skeleton v-show="bannersLoading || list?.length === 0" />
  </section>
</template>

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      color: 'black',
      swiperEl: null,
    }
  },
  computed: {
    computedList() {
      return [...Array(5).fill(this.list)].flat()
    },
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapMutations(['SET_NAVBAR_COLOR']),
    onChangeSlide() {
      const color = document.querySelector('.swiper-slide-fully-visible')
        ?.dataset.color
      this.setColor(color)
    },
    setColor(color = this.color) {
      this.color = color
      this.SET_NAVBAR_COLOR(color)
    },
  },
  watch: {
    list() {
      this.onChangeSlide()
    },
  },

  mounted() {
    this.swiperEl = this.$refs.swiper

    const swiperParams = {
      slidesPerView: 1,
      loopAddBlankSlides: true,
      loop: true,
      effect: 'fade',
      speed: 600,
      autoplay: {
        disableOnInteraction: false,
        delay: 2000,
      },
    }

    Object.assign(this.swiperEl, swiperParams)

    this.swiperEl.initialize()

    this.swiperEl.addEventListener('swiperslidechange', this.onChangeSlide)
  },
  components,
  props,
}

On some browsers, autoplay starts successfully, and on some it starts after you manually flip through the slide or lock/unlock the phone.
I tried adding console.log(color) to onChangeSlide. On those browsers where autoplay is started, undefined goes to the console 2 times, then the color value comes out. And in browsers where autoplay does not work, undefined just comes out 2 times, and edit does not come out.
